# ckeditor integration with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how will i integrate ckdeditor with asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the integration instructions on [this page](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration) maybe. There isn't anything special about integrating CKeditor with asp.net mvc.

Comment: ckeditor is the best with very less loading time much lesser then fckeditor latest version

Answer (score 0):

Here I have integrated CKEDITOR with MVC4 Razor view Application.

[**Click here**](http://mvcanswers.blogspot.in/) to Read this blog.